# Distance from right border of image to right border of the image's parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to determine the distance from the right border of image 2 to the right border of the image's parent div.

```
//The images will be aligned horizontally as in the image bellow
<div class = "parent-div">
    <img src "img01.jpg" />
    <img src "img02.jpg" />
    <img src "img03.jpg" />
    <img src "img04.jpg" />
    <img src "img05.jpg" />
</div>
```

I have used CSS to specify the width of the images and the parent div as follows:

```
.parent-div{
    width: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.parent-div > img{
    width:100px;
}
```

Example from the image below, what is the distance from the right border of image 2 to the right border of the parent div in JQuery or JavaScript?
[image]

Comment: Are you referring to padding area?

Comment: Yes the padding area, for example from image 2

Comment: getBoundingClientRect should help! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: @Hans I have tried the `getBoundingClientRect();` at the link you provided. After some hours on it, I am yet to understand it. Although the parent div is `470px` in width, when I used `getBoundingClientRect();` I got e.g `left: 683.` How exactly can I use `getBoundingClientRect();` in my case to obtain the answer I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

As [described in the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` will get the element position relative to the viewport, as well as some other values like its own width and height. With the latter, you can geht width and height of the container.

Then, getting the values for the child image, you can calculate the value.

```js
var containerEl = document.querySelector('.parent-div');
var containerElRect = containerEl.getBoundingClientRect();
var containerElWidth = containerElRect.width;

// This selects all img elements
var imgElements = containerEl.querySelectorAll('img');

// This selects the second image
var imgEl = imgElements[1];
var imgElRect = imgEl.getBoundingClientRect();
var imgElWidth = imgElRect.width;

// This is the offset from the left border of the image to the left border of the container
var imgElOffsetLeft = imgEl.offsetLeft;

// Calculate the value you search for:
var theDistance = containerElWidth - imgElWidth - imgElOffsetLeft;

console.log(theDistance);
```

```css
.parent-div {
  /* This is important for `imgEl.offsetLeft` to work! 
  The nearest positioned parent is looked for with offsetParent. */
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
  
  /* Only to kill spaces between images */
  font-size: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.parent-div > img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" />
</div>
```